# 操{みさお} : too many translations to be true

Tags: translation, kanji

I am a bit confused regarding the translations of the word 操 in my 漢字 book (Kanji et Kana of Hadamitzky, Durmous and Mochizuki), as they give : chastity, purity, innocence, constancy, fidelity and honour! So I wanted to know which ones were closer to the actual usage of this word, as most of these translations have already well-known equivalents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to be strict in meaning, let's use those well-known equivalents :-)

Honestly speaking, I find it hard to explain how it is actually used, because it's rarely used. Everyone has heard this word, typically sung in [enka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enka) and Japanese folk songs (for example see [なみだの操](https://youtu.be/SXqiXYnuv84)). But the concept of 操 is almost never used in today's education, discussions, essays, and so on.

If I understand correctly, 操 is basically an old-fashioned word which is close to 貞操 (chastity). It does not necessarily mean being a 処女 (virgin), and 操 can probably be used with a married woman. I tend to associate 操 with a stereotype of strong-minded, determined woman who is faithful to her husband or master.

When I was writing this, Joan of Arc came up to my mind...although she's not even a Japanese!

Comment: Thank you very much naruto! Also, as chastity came first, I guess I can use this word it for this primary sense only, or I risk to be unclear.